# How to output a Numpy Array with clusters on basis of two arrays with data and labels

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I would like to implement a function which does the following:

```
Receives a labeled dataset and splits the datapoints according to label

Args:
    X (np.ndarray): The dataset
    y (np.ndarray): The label for each point in the dataset

Returns:
    List[np.ndarray]: A list of arrays where the elements of each array
    are datapoints belonging to the label at that index.
    
Example:
>>> get_clusters(
        np.array([[0.8, 0.7], [0, 0.4], [0.3, 0.1]]), 
        np.array([0,1,0])
    )
>>> [array([[0.8, 0.7],[0.3, 0.1]]), 
     array([[0. , 0.4]])]
```

I'm currently a bit lost as I don't find any way to write into a certain index of the Numpy Array, so I can only append to the array, instead of append to the array in index 0 where I have the datapoint with label = 0.

Here is my current code:

```
i = 0 
labels = {}
clusters = np.array([
        ])


for a in y:
    if a in labels:
        il = labels[a]
        clusters = np.append(clusters,X[i])
    else:
        labels[a] = i
        clusters = np.append(clusters,X[i])
    i+=1
    
    

return clusters
```

Can anybody help me with implementing the function? Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
def get_clusters(X, y):
    return [X[np.where(y==i)] for i in range(np.amax(y)+1)]
```

Here, `np.amax(y)+1` calculates the length of the list, assuming it to be from `0` to the maximum value in `y` (this can be changed if necessary). Then, `np.where(y==i)` finds indices of each label, which are then selected from `X`. The order of the for loop ensures that each index corresponds to the label of that value.

Comment: While your (elegant, upvoted) solution works with the test case provided, what if the labels are sparse, or even they are non-numeric (`'A'`, `'C'`, `'Q'`)? I'd suggest `... for i in sorted(set(y))`

Comment: @gboffi Thanks, I agree with you, but I think that would not satisfy the OP's specification: "A list of arrays where the elements of each array are datapoints belonging to the label at that index.". Each datapoint's index would no longer be its label. So I assumed that the data is such that the issues you mentioned wouldn't arise.